# Are there any fake hats?

Tags: support, winterbash-2013

Would the SE team possibly include any fake hats to throw us off?

I was trying to figure out which hat to earn next and didn't want to spend my time on a hat that was just there as a tease.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  Look at the spritesheet:

[image]

Some of those hats have been achieved by ***nobody***.  Proof enough for me that they are fakes.

Comment: Are you sure that it's not because the criteria for the hats were just too stringent for someone to earn them? There are some [badges](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/badges/35/unsung-hero) that haven't been earned, but I don't believe they are fake badges.

Comment: @J.R. Quite possibly. In fact, "Don Draper" isn't even on the spritesheet!

Answer (score 5):

Yes. They included at least [three red herrings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160069/what-is-nicholas-cage-doing-in-winter-bash) in the graphics last year to throw people off.

You can see from the sheet last year:
[image: 2012 hats]

Comment: Last year's hats were much more detailed.

Comment: I think they were watered down this year in favor of being able to position them on avatars.